# Gcc Error No Such File or Directory

Tags: gnu-make, makefile

I've been working on this for two days and still haven't been able to get this makefile to work.

This is what I currently have:

```
INCDIR = inc/pvt inc/pub
SRCDIR = src
OBJDIR = obj
LIBDIR = lib

CC=gcc
CFLAGS := $(foreach d, $(INCDIR), -I$d)

_SRC = teos_event.c teos_init.c teos_linkedlist.c teos_log.c teos_sem.c teos_task.c
_OBJ := $(subst $(SRCDIR),$(OBJDIR),$(_SRC:%.c=%.o))
OBJ := $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

build: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) -fmax-errors=1

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) -fmax-errors=1

$(OBJ): $(DEPS)
```

This is the output I get when I run make:

```
gcc -o build obj/teos_event.o obj/teos_init.o obj/teos_linkedlist.o obj/teos_log
.o obj/teos_sem.o obj/teos_task.o  -Iinc/pvt  -Iinc/pub -fmax-errors=1
gcc: error: obj/teos_event.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: obj/teos_init.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: obj/teos_linkedlist.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: obj/teos_log.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: obj/teos_sem.o: No such file or directory
gcc: error: obj/teos_task.o: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
makefile:40: recipe for target 'build' failed
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

I'm trying to get it to build without makefile errors.  Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you not notice that it isn't building `teos_event.o`?

Change this:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    ...
```

to this:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    ...
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm at noob at make, and it's syntax seems so archaic.  Thanks so much!